# Broken link users/tag-notifications/0#watching-1

Tags: bug, anonymous-user, tag-watching

When a not logged in user visits the following URL:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=intags%3amine%20is%3aquestion

A text is displayed:

> Improve your results by setting your favorite tags.

Which links to broken link:
https://stackoverflow.com/users/tag-notifications/0#watching-1

Comment: I can reproduce this without constraining the search to questions, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Intags%3Amine